# How to scrape all data in the pop windows using python/beautifulsoup/selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have looked into many things but i cant seem to find solution for this.
I am trying to scrape https://orbispatches.com/en/CUSA11260 but the issue is that the description of these patch notes is embedded in the pop ups and it dynamically loads which makes it impossible to scrape the front end.

[this is a patch note i want to scrape , click it which opens the next image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLWxn.png)

[this description needs to scraped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqxvu.png)

Also, this just one example on the page. I would like to scrape all popups on the page.

Any help would be much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: The results you are looking for are pulled from a POST request to another API. Check your Network tab for this API url, for the data you need to post it to, etc. I don't remember seeing another website flooded with advertising and tracking like this one... I regret opening it. You might be forced to use selenium to obtain that data.

Comment: hi. thanks for your reply. i have checked the network tab but couldnt find it. can you tell me where exactly i can look for it?

Comment: The network tab is flooded with calls to trackers and advertisers exchanges (seriosuly, it's horrible), so you need to try harder, and you will see a POST being made to orbispatches. Inspect it and you will see the data needed to be sent, and also the response

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but you can try this:

```
    import time

import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException


url = 'https://orbispatches.com/en/CUSA11260'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
#chrome_options.add_argument(f"--window-size=1980,4000")
#chrome_options.add_argument("--hide-scrollbars")
result_dict = {}

with webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) as browser:
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1000)")
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'input').send_keys(Keys.TAB)

    try:
        for i in range(1, 16):
            css_sel_btn = f'body > main > div > div.row.my-5 > div.col-lg-8 > div:nth-child({i}) > nav > a.nav-link.changelog-link'
            btn_notes = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_sel_btn)
            btn_notes.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            tittle = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'dynamicModal').text
            description = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#modal-dyn > span').text
            result_dict.update({tittle: description})
            browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#dynmodal > div > div > div.modal-header > button > svg > path').click()
            browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 300)")
            time.sleep(1)
            btn_notes.send_keys(Keys.TAB)

    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        browser.close()

print(result_dict)
```

Change the code to suit your needs =)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).